# Pop up remove scrolling and fix pop up block

Tags: javascript, html, css

So there is my code on pop-up. I want it to take full page( except header), but the rest of the content is not visible. How can i make it? Remove scrolling or fix pop up block?Also   i am looking for the way to make hedaer visible without padding, if its possible. I understand that prodlem cause of padding-top, but i need it for header. Thanks.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzLf6g8d/3/) if needed.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.color{width:100%;
height:2000px;
background-color:blue;}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class = "color">

 </div>
```

Comment: so where is your header?

Comment: @MhdAlaaAlhaj is it important? Its just simple block with links. Lets think that i need to see buttoт  instead of header,

Answer (score 1):

**Modal changes:**

1. Remove padding-top
2. Add `top: 100px` - use the height of your header.
3. Use calculated height, i.e. `height: calc(100% - 100px)` - subtract headers height from it.

**Modal show event:**

1. Make the body `overflow: hidden` so that it won't scroll.